# Own machine not connecting to virtual machine(which is acting as a server)

Tags: ubuntu, jboss, virtual-machine, remote-access

I am trying to access jboss remotely on the virtual machine. I have completed the following steps

1. Change network adapter in the VM to "Host Only Adapter" and set promiscous     mode to "Allow AI"(VM was shut down to do this
2. Connection was tested between laptop and VM by checking the IP of the VM and pinging from laptop to the VM using ping (IPVM) and this has connected fine
3. I then tested the access to my localhost:8080/myapp but first added an additional parameter to jboss by typing ./run.sh -b 0.0.0.0 with the -b 0.0.0.0 part changing behavior of jboss to listen to all ip's in the server

However when I try typing in (IP_OF_VM):8080/myapp it says this site cannot be reached. Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this is happening? Thanks in advance